# RubyMotion RMQ default global styles

Tags: ios, styles, stylesheet, rubymotion, rmq

I'd like have default styles for `UIView`s.

Let's say that I want to have ALL `UILabel` with `backgroundColor` of `color.light_gray`.
Moreover I want to style my custom `UIView`s, e.g. for EVERY `AttributedUILabel` I want to have `kerning` value set to `2`.

How to resolve that in RMQ?

Comment: -1 without explanation, that's why i like the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RMQ application, you should have an ApplicationStylesheet class from which all your other stylesheets should inherit.

You could add a default_label method in this ApplicationStylesheet:

```
def default_label(st)
  st.background_color = color.light_gray
end
```

To apply the style you would have to use it when you append your label

```
rmq.append UILabel, :default_label
```

Same goes for your AttributeUILabel, create a method in your ApplicationStylesheet and use the style when you append it to the view.

I suggest you go back to the [RMQ stylesheets documentation](http://rubymotionquery.com/documentation/#cat-10), it shows everything you need to know about styling.

Comment: I use this solution right now, but it's not perfect, because it forces me to remember about it each time I create `UILabel`. With TeaCup I have it out of the box, so I'm used to style some kind of `UIView` in one place and doesn't bother to remember anymore.